# How to install DirectX redistributable from Inno-setup?

Tags: installation, directx, inno-setup

I didn't find any tip about DirectX installation at Inno-Setup web site. So, is there any sample installation script? I know that I have to add to [Run] sction something like this:

```
Filename: "{src}\DirectX\DXSETUP.exe"; WorkingDir: "{src}\DirectX"; Parameters: "/silent"; Check: DirectX; Flags: waituntilterminated; BeforeInstall: DirectXProgress;
```

But how to include it into setup file (temp folder?), how to extract it, ect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To include it in the setup, you can install it to `{tmp}` and then `[Run]` it from there.

The correct way to install this sort of requirement is to extract in code and call `Exec()` on it in the `PrepareToInstall()` event function:

```
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
  InstallerResult: integer;
begin
  //Check if .Net is available already
  if NeedsDirectX() then begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('DXSETUP.exe');
    if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\DXSETUP.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, InstallerResult) then begin
      case InstallerResult of
        0: begin
          //It installed successfully (Or already was), we can continue
        end;
        else begin
          //Some other error
          result := 'DirectX installation failed. Exit code ' + IntToStr(InstallerResult);
        end;
      end;
    end else begin
      result := 'DirectX installation failed. ' + SysErrorMessage(InstallerResult);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The ISXKB has an [article on how to detect the versions installed](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=DirectX_-_How_to_detect_DirectX_version).

Comment: Where does this function `NeedsDirectX()` come from?